# Nginx 500 Interal Server Error with React app - 1 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html"

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx

Here's my nginx default.conf file:

```
server {
    listen 3000;

    location / {
        root usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14-slim as builder
WORKDIR "/app"
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx
EXPOSE 3000
COPY ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

If I look inside my Docker container, I can see the files are all where they should be: [image]

Also for context, I'm also using nginx for routing, with this config:

```
upstream client {
    server client:3000;
}

upstream api {
    server api:3001;
}

server {
    listen 81;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://client;
    }

    location /api {
        rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://api;
    }

     location /sockjs-node {
        proxy_pass http://client;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

}
```

However, if I try to navigate to localhost:81, I get this error:

```
client_1   | 2021/02/18 15:46:35 [error] 28#28: *10 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 172.18.0.3, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", host: "client"
```

Any ideas what the issue could be? Most other threads I've looked at focus on this bit, but I already have it and I'm sure the file locations are all correct.:

```
server {
    listen 3000;

    location / {
        root usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; <-- this line here
    }
}
```

Another thread suggested adding `"homepage": "./`" to the `package.json` file, but this didn't seem to make any difference either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was able to get an answer from [Michael Hampton](https://serverfault.com/a/1054309/618153) on serverfault:

> Fix the typo in your root directive.

> The leading / is missing, thus nginx considers the path relative to a compiled-in default (usually /etc/nginx on Linux).

> What is actually happening is that the directory /etc/nginx/usr/share/nginx/html does not exist. So when processing try_files, nginx first tries $uri which fails, then it tries $uri/ which processes the paths in the index directive. None of these exist either. Finally it reaches /index.html, which it feeds back to try_files, but as that is the same path it just tried in index processing, it detects the infinite loop and bails out.

So all I had to do was change this

```
root usr/share/nginx/html;
```

to this:

```
root /usr/share/nginx/html;
```

Comment: Wow this is so insane but if you installed in Mac OS via homebrew the problem is actually the opposite, you have to remove the slash from the front in order to get the path to match up. What a headache.